# CMake not finding Boost program_options building PokerStove on Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmake, boost, poker, cmake-gui

I'm currently working on a project that involves using PokerStove, and I'm trying to use CMake gui to build the PokerStove library (https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove) on my Windows 10 Home (Version 1809) machine. However, I'm encountering issues with CMake not finding the program_options component of Boost.

Here are the details of my setup:

CMake version: 3.27.6
Boost version: 1.83.0
Compiler: Microsoft Visual Studio 17 2022
Operating System: Windows 10 Home, Version 1809

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(pokerstove)

# Set C++ standard to C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Remove the deprecated register keywords
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-deprecated-register")

# Set up gtest
add_subdirectory(src/ext/googletest)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTEST_LIBS_DIR})
add_definitions("-fPIC")
enable_testing()

# Set up Boost
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Set the Boost library directory
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS "C:/Users/baumn/Downloads/boost_1_83_0/boost_1_83_0/stage/lib")

link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message(STATUS "Boost Include: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost Library Dirs: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost Libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

# Include PROJECT_BINARY_DIR for config.h
include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

# Set the output directory for executables
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# add the actual code
add_subdirectory(src)

# Add make install functionality
install(TARGETS peval)
install(TARGETS penum)
install(TARGETS ps-colex)
install(TARGETS ps-eval)
install(TARGETS ps-lut)
```

When I run CMake to configure the project, I'm encountering the following error:

CMake Error at .../FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
Could NOT find Boost (missing: program_options) (found version "1.83.0")

I have already tried the following:

Ensured that Boost is correctly installed on my system. - (I successfully compiled a simple c++ program that used Boost.Asio)

Checked the Boost library directory and verified that the program_options library exists.
Set the BOOST_LIBRARYDIR variable in my CMakeLists.txt.
I set the environment variable BOOST_ROOT to the directory where I installed boost

Can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this problem while building PokerStove using CMake on Windows 10?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: According to the error message (`found version "1.83.0"`) CMake has found Boost headers, but failed to find libraries. Probably, your installed libraries are incompatible with the CMake generator you use. Set `Boost_DEBUG` option (e.g. by passing `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` to `cmake`) and inspect CMake output when configure your project. In that output CMake will print exact directories where it searches Boost libraries, and exact possible names of those libraries. Compare these directories and names with files you actually have in your Boost installation.

Comment: I added the line
set(Boost_DEBUG ON) 
to my CMakeLists.txt file and found that there was a mismatch with the names of the library files. 
My file was named 'libboost_program_options-vc143-mt-x64-1_83.lib'

it was looking for 'boost_program_options-vc143-mt-x64-1_83.lib'
I renamed my file to the name it was looking for and everything seems to have worked successfully.
Thank you!

Comment: According to the [Boost naming conventions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming), `lib` prefix means **static** library. By default, `find_package(Boost)` searches for the **shared** libraries. For search static libraries, set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` variable to ON ([documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html#other-variables)).